# Converting from php mysql to mysqli mysqli_fetch_array

Tags: php, mysqli

I am in the middle of converting a program from the mysql library to mysqli.

Edit:  Some more context

I have the following code calling a class

```
case "purchasing";
    $tab = 'purchasing';
    require $classes . 'purchasing.php';
    $purchases = new Purchase_list($search_term, $scope);
    require $templates . 'header.php';
    require $templates . 'purchasing.php';
    break;
```

The class that contains get_result below is Purchase_list
Purchase list basically figures out what rows to retrieve from the database, runs a query and assigns the results to $this->result

That part is obviously working since I have a valid result.
Then $templates . 'purchasing.php'; displays those results.

For trouble shooting purposes purchasing.php only contains

```
while ($row = $purchases->get_result()) {

}
```

I have a function inside a class that looks like this

```
function get_result() {

    $results = mysqli_fetch_array($this->result);        
    if($results === FALSE) {
        return false;
    }else {
        $results['OPENAMT'] = ($results['Puramt'] - $results['Recamt']);

        return $results;
    }


}
```

if I comment out the the $results['OPENAMT'] code everything works great, with that code not commented it times out the browser request.
This code worked with the mysql extension instead of mysqli

Can anyone shed any light on whats actually going on here.

a var_dump on $results before trying to return gives

```
array(11) {
  [0]=> string(5) "23074"
  ["Purno"]=> string(5) "23074"
  [1]=> string(3) "AEC"
  ["Vendno"]=> string(3) "AEC"
  [2]=> string(10) "11/28/2012"
  ["Purdate"]=> string(10) "11/28/2012"
  [3]=> string(4) "0.00"
  ["Puramt"]=> string(4) "0.00"
  [4]=> string(4) "0.00" 
  ["Recamt"]=> string(4) "0.00"
  ["OPENAMT"]=> float(0)
}
```

Comment: What does `$results` look like?

Comment: Please post a `var_dump($results)`

Comment: And please post the var_dump in your **question** not as a comment!

Comment: Any reason you're not using `mysqli_fetch_assoc()`? If you're not referencing the results by a numeric index...

Comment: And it seems to work, `["OPENAMT"]=> float(0)` is in the array. Maybe the issue is somewhere else in your code? Like the part that tries to access `OPENAMT` after it returns.

Comment: I started out with mysqli_fetch_assoc() at some point of trying everything I can think of I switched

Comment: `<?php
$results['Puramt'] = "4.00";
$results['Recamt'] = "8.00";

$results['OPENAMT'] = ($results['Puramt'] - $results['Recamt']);

var_dump( $results );
?>`
works fine. Are you sure your code breaks in there?

Comment: At this point i'm so frustrated and confused, I feel like I must be missing something, so I put a simplified test case in the question, I have verified the test case exhibits the same behaviour.  Whats really strange is I can change back to mysql extension and everything works

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't exactly know why you get this problem, but I hope this may help.

Whereas `mysql_fetch_array` returns `FALSE` when there are no more rows to fetch, `mysqli_fetch_arrays` returns `NULL`.

So `$results` is never `=== FALSE`, and you always get into the `else` block and probably return some rubbish with warnings being fired.

As a consequence, the `while` loop calling `get_result()` never ends because instead of getting `false` it gets *I don't know what*.

Comment: Ahh that would make perfect sense.  I feel so dumb now, I have read the documentation on mysqli_fetch_arrays 100 times now and missed that everytime

Comment: OK, after you try the fix I'll be glad to know if it really solves the issue.

Comment: It definitely fixed the problem.  I would upvote your answer if I could!